# Create new JSON item in an array

Tags: c#, json, new-operator, nullreferenceexception

I'm setting my first steps in C# and JSON.

I've installed Web Essentials in my Visual Studio environment, and I've used it to create a JSON class structure.

My JSON looks as follows:

```
{
    "project": {
        "common.DESCRIPTION": "Project_Description",
        ...
        "locations": [
            {
                "common.NAME": "Location_Name",
                ...
```

The Web Essentials "Paste Special" (for creating the classes out of the JSON) generated something like:

```
public class Project
{
    public string commonDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    ...
    public Location[] locations { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Location
{
    public string commonNAME { get; set; }
    ...
```

My code looks as follows:

```
Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
for (int i = 0; i < listbox_with_names.Items.Count; i++)
{
    root.project = new Project();
    root.project.locations[i] = new Location();
    root.project.locations[i].commonNAME = listbox_with_names.Items[i].ToString();
```

This code fails because the locations have `null` value, causing a `NullPointerException`.
However, `root` and `project` seem to be fine.

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong in this line:

```
root.project.locations[i] = new Location();
```

Does anybody know how to declare an object, which is to be a part of an array, in C#? (Or am I completely wrong using the `new` operator as I've done for `root` and `project`?)

P.S. there is the comment that my question is a duplicate of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but this post is extremely large and it's extremely difficult to find back the one issue I'm dealing with (if it's even mentioned there, I had a look and I felt like "TL;DR" (too long, didn't read), sorry).

Comment: `root.project.locations = new Location[0];`, More information in the official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays

Comment: Use this to initialize `locations`, it does not happen by itself: `root.project = new Project { locations = new Location[numberOfLocations] }`. You need to determine the value for `numberOfLocations` from somewhere, and it must be at least `1` or else the array can't store any items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220550/peter-b) and some debugging, I found the solution: 2 individual constructors need to be run as you can see:

```
Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
root.project = new Project();
root.project.locations = new Location[listbox_with_names.Items.Count]; // construct the array
for (int i = 0; i < listbox_with_names.Items.Count; i++)
{
    root.project.locations[i] = new Location(); // construct each array member separately
```